# How to show $[i]+[j]= [i+j]$ and $[i][j]= [ij]$ where $[i], [j]$ belong to the set of congruence class of mod $n$?

Tags: integers

I was reading about the congruence modulo $n$ in *The Integers* from *Topics in Algebra* by *I.N. Herstein*; after showing the congruence modulo relation is equivalent, he introduced the set of all congruence classes viz. $J_n$ as:

> [...] Let $J_n$ be the set of the congruence classes mod $n$; that is, $J_n = \{[0],[1],\ldots, [n-1]\}\:.$ Given two elements, $[i]$ and $[j]$ in $J_n,$ let us **define** \begin{align}[i]+[j] &= [i+j]\tag a\\ [i][j]&= [ij]\tag b\end{align} [...]

He then told they can be shown to be well-defined and jot down few properties which are left as exercise.

However, I didn't get how the author got motivated by "**defining**" whatever they are in that way above.

He didn't tell us why they are true or whether they are valid; the **definition** just came from nowhere.

Could anyone shed some light on how to show the relations are true? Or is it that they are **defined** so?

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer to say that there exists a ring homomorphism between $\Bbb Z$ and $J_n$ for every $n \in \Bbb N$

Comment: I would appreciate if you elaborate @cronos2.

Comment: The objective is to endow $J_n$ with a ring structure. The difficulty is to make sure the definition is well defined. This means that no matter the value of $i+j$ (respectively $i\cdot j$) that is not necessarily $\lt n$ we get $[i+j]\in J_n$ (respectively $[i\cdot j]\in J_n$) and what we get is unique. It is obvious but requires to be noted.

Comment: @marwalix, Herstein indeed shows the relations are well-defined in in the following discussion; but he didn't introduce the concept of ring then. I'd love to see your comment as an answer and would appreciate how it is related with the concept of ring.

Answer (score 1):

The objective is to endow $J_n$ with a ring structure. Indeed to have a ring you need two operations and you can check that the ring axioms are verified, the neutral for addition being $[0]$ and the neutral for multiplication being $[1]$.

The difficulty is to make sure the definition is well defined. This means that no matter the value of $i+j$ that is not necessarily $\lt n$ we get $[i+j]\in J_n$  and what we get is unique. It is obvious but requires to be noted.

Comment: Thanks for making the comment as an answer; +1 for that' I'll accept that when I start studying ring theory and have a sufficient rigor to handle problems on the same.